# GPO Outlook 2013 to set non-cached mode is preventing Outlook from opening

Tags: group-policy, outlook

I have a GPO applied to my conference room computers that forces Outlook to use non-cached mode (for quicker opening and to save HDD space by preventing everyone's OST from being created).  When I try to open Outlook it gives me an error message that says

> Cannot start Microsoft Outlook. Cannot open the Outlook window. The set of folders cannot be opened. The attempt to log on to Microsoft Exchange has failed.

If I go into the email accounts in control panel, click the account, repair it and then open Outlook, it opens right up.  Has anyone else seen this issue while forcing non-cached mode in Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook 2013 you will be much better off setting the OST to a minimal amount of time to cache, i.e. 1 month.  This will result in a very light OST file and a full-featured client (Exchange Search kicks in more often due to the small amount of info cached).  This is general advice, and certainly might not work in your situation for your org.

Is there anything in the GPO that specifies profile setup?  This sounds like Autodiscover is failing during the out-of-box "pre-setup", then works fine when you run the wizard manually. Is that accurate?

Comment: That is accurate. There is nothing in the GPO that modifies Autodiscover

Comment: Are there any Outlook profile settings specified in your installer created with the Office Deployment Tool?  (MSP or MST, I forget which one it uses)